# sed - replace only 1 instance and delete the rest

Tags: bash, sed

I currently have the following command block of code that will compare two literal strings and replace it with what is expected if they are not equal. While this works wonderfully if there is exactly one instance of the actual string, how do I improve it so it will only replace the first finding and delete the others?

```
if [ "$actualString" != "$expectedString" ]; then
    sed -i 's|$actualString|$expectedString|g' /tmp/test
fi
```

Edit: I will be dealing with ssh keys, so $actualString would be one key or in the case where there's multiple occurrences, multiple keys on different lines. So for instance:

```
key user1@host1
key user2@host2
key user1@host1
key user3@host3
key user1@host1
```

I want to replace only the first instance that has user1@host1 with "monkey user1@host1", and delete the rest. I'm looking for my file to be updated as so

```
monkey user1@host1
key user2@host2
key user3@host3
```

Comment: The use of single quotes in your `sed` command means that the values of `$actualString` and `$expectedString` will not be expanded. Perhaps you should update your question. Also, are you asking about multiple instances on the same line, or occurrences on different lines?

Comment: Updated per request.

Comment: Did you try my perl command as suggested?

Comment: I did. How do I get it to update the actual file?

Answer (score 0):

Easier to do this using `perl -0` that slurps whole file in one go:

```
perl -0pe "s|$actualString|$expectedString|; s|$actualString||g"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to save the first occurrence of a duplicated user, delete the rest and add monkey:

```
sort -u inputfile.txt | sed -e "0,/$(sort inputfile.txt | uniq -d)/s/^key /monkey /"
```

Substitute `sed -i` for `sed -e` to edit the file in place (or `sed -i.bak` to create a backup of the original in `inputfile.txt.bak` while editing in place.)

**output:**

```
$ sort -u dat/keys.txt | sed -e "0,/$(sort dat/keys.txt | uniq -d)/s/^key /monkey /"
monkey user1@host1
key user2@host2
key user3@host3
```

**NOTE:** this presumes one duplicated user. For additional duplicates, an array of the results of `uniq -d` would need to be kept.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following

```
key user1@host1
key user2@host2
key user1@host1
key user3@host3
key user1@host1
key user2@host2
key user3@host3
key user1@host1
key user1@host2
```

find the first occurence of `key user1@host1` and change it, then delete the rest of duplicates do:

```
sed -e '0,/key user1@host1/s/key user1@host1/............../' -e '/key user1@host1/d' 'my_file'
```

output

```
..............
key user2@host2
key user3@host3
key user2@host2
key user3@host3
key user1@host2
```

Comment: a lot of output but nothing useful